# How to iterate array that have list of arrays?

Tags: java

I have a problem i dont know how to iterate this:

```
[
  [
    "DIRECT_SALES",
    "R_CATEGORY",
    "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,28",
    null
  ],
  [
    "PROGRAMMATIC",
    "R_USAGE_TYPE",
    "DESKTOP,MOBILE,APP",
    null
  ]
]
```

Any suggestion how can i iterate through this ?

What im trying to do is to get second and third values in this array and pass it to another method. So in new method i will have : method(R_CATEGORY, 1,2,3,4...) ;

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited my post and write what im trying to achive.

Comment: What's wrong with that:`for (String[] subarr: arr) method(subarr[1], subarr[2].split(","))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `String[][] myArrays` and you can do something like:

```
 for (String[] firstArray:myArrays){
      for (String str:firstArray){
         //Do something ex: System.out.println(str);
      }
 }
```

or if you prefer:

```
   for (int i=0; i<myArrays.length; i++){
      for ( int j=0; j<myArrays[i].length; j++){
        //Do something ex:System.out.println(myArrays[i][j]);
      }
    }
```

In your case:

```
    String[] strings1 = { "DIRECT_SALES",
        "R_CATEGORY",
        "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,28",
        null
    };

    String[] strings2 = {
        "PROGRAMMATIC",
        "R_USAGE_TYPE",
        "DESKTOP,MOBILE,APP",
        null
    };

    String[][]  myArrays = {strings1,strings2};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as **dyukha** suggested because it's super short. Here's another solution:

```
    String[] array = {"blah", "hey", "hahaha"};
    String[] array2 = {"another blah", "hello", "hohoho"};

    Object[] object;
    object = new Object[]{array, array2};

    for(int i = 0 ; i < object.length; i++) {
        String[] o = (String[])object[i];

        String firstValue;
        String secondValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < o.length; j++) {
            if (j==0)
                firstValue = o[j];
            if (j==1)
                secondValue = o[j];
        }

        methodCall(firstValue, secondValue);
    }
```

Don't know anything about the object and whether you want any additional checking.